# How to make Windows use different NICs based on URL or IP

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have 2 network cards on my PC, connecting to different networks. How can I switch them based on URLs or IPs i'm visiting?

I use routing tables for this on Linux, maybe there're similar functionalities on Windows?

Comment: Windows has routing tables as well.  You should be able to setup the routing similarly.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/route.html

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, that helped. It would be nice if you post it as an answer so that I can close this question :)

Comment: @LotusH No problem. Answer posted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I use routing tables for this on Linux, is there something similar Windows?

Windows has the [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) command:

> **ROUTE.exe**
>
> Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.
>
> Syntax
>
> Display route details:
>
> ```
> ROUTE [-f] PRINT [destination_host] [MASK subnet_mask_value] [gateway]    
>     [METRIC metric] [IF interface_no.]
> ```
>
> Add a route:
>
> ```
> ROUTE [-f] [-p] ADD [destination_host] [MASK subnet_mask_value] [gateway] 
>     [METRIC metric] [IF interface_no.]
> ```
>
> Change a route:
>
> ```
> ROUTE [-f] CHANGE [destination_host] [MASK subnet_mask_value] [gateway] 
>     [METRIC metric] [IF interface_no.]
> ```
>
> Delete a route:
>
> ```
> ROUTE [-f] DELETE [destination_host] [MASK subnet_mask_value] [gateway] 
>     [METRIC metric] [IF interface_no.]
> ```
>
> Key
>
> - `-f` - Clear (flush) the routing tables of all gateway entries.
>
>   If this is used in conjunction with one of the commands, the tables
>     are cleared prior to running the command.
> - `destination_host` - The address (or set of addresses) that you want to reach.
> - `-p` - Create a persistent route - survives system reboots. (not supported in Windows 95)
> - `subnet_mask_value` - The subnet mask value for this route entry.
>
>   This defines how many addresses are there.
>
>   If not specified, it defaults to 255.255.255.255.
> - `gateway` - The gateway.
> - `interface` - The interface number (1,2,...) for the specified route.
>                  If the option `IF interface_no` is not given, ROUTE will try to find the best interface available.
> - `metric` - The metric, ie. cost for the destination.

Source [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.